# Is it possible to customize / configure the signing process?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I would like actually to be able to do some modifications on the layout we receive once we get https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?t=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx

[image]

So there I would like to remove :

- the whole 'other actions' button/menu
- the whole block with css class: 'title', 'id-card', 'image', 'information'
- removing the padding of the body to get the document a little higher (in place of the above information block)

Is there a way to give parameters to get a custom layout for this session, or we have to do 'dirty things' in order to remove those elements from the DOM after we loaded it from the url ?

Thanks !

Edit: Actually we are not allowed to access the elements of the received frame:
[image]

Remaining only query strings options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole options are there: 
https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-signing-resource-file(v1.1).pdf

It is in the admin menu, under 'Brands' menu, and you need to 'edit' an existing label in order to access the ressource file management :)